# Strech image to fill the transparent background using Magick.NET

Tags: c#, image, imagemagick, magick.net

I have an image (attached).
[image]

I want the image to be stretched out to cover the yellow area.

I am using c#, [magick.net](http://magick.codeplex.com/)

What will be the best approach?

Comment: So the yellow area in your image is not actually yellow, but transparent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose the following approach:

1. read input image saving original size
2. remove the transparent* area using `trim`
3. stretch the (now smaller) image to the original size

*If the yellow area in your sample image is actually transparent you can leave `fuzz = 0` in the following code, otherwise you'll have to adjust the value to be sure to remove all the unwanted area.

```
string srcImageFullPath = "c:\input.png";
int fuzz = 0;
string destImageFullPath = "c:\output.png";

// Read image from file
using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(srcImageFullPath))
{
    //save height/width of the original image
    int height = image.Page.Height;
    int width = image.Page.Width;

    //set fuzz percentage
    image.ColorFuzz = new ImageMagick.Percentage(fuzz);

    //trim borders
    image.Trim();

    //resize image to original size
    MagickGeometry size = new MagickGeometry(width, height);
    size.IgnoreAspectRatio = true;
    image.Resize(size);

    // Save the result
    image.Write(destImageFullPath);
}
```

In the following picture you can see the original image on the left, and the image after resizing on the right:

[image]

*Notes*

1. `Trim` removes any border that has the same color of the pixels in the corner of you image (see [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#trim) for the details)
2. Since the yellow border in your sample image is not made of a single color you can use `Fuzz` to remove "similar" colors (more info [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#trim_fuzz)). As said before if your border is transparent just leave `fuzz = 0`